# Difference between stock markets exchange for a stock

Tags: stocks, stock-markets, stock-analysis, stock-exchanges

I saw a variation of this answered a few times.

I wanted to use the example of Reliance Industries (India)

On DEGIRO you find it listed under Frankfurt stock exchange and London Stock Exchange with slightly varying price. However, its price list in Indian Rupee once searched on google is substantially lower than the ones listed in European Market,

What is the explanation for this?
Thanks

Comment: Please add screenshots, links, specific prices, and currency conversion calculations. Thank you.

Comment: "I saw a variation of this answered a few times" — Where? Could you provide links? (I would like the links so that I can edit/compare/answer the related questions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Reliance's [Investors' Handbook](https://www.ril.com/getattachment/0f55d265-780c-4c2f-8502-bba3513e3829/Investors-Handbook.aspx) and "[Shareholders’ Referencer](https://www.ril.com/DownloadFiles/IRForms/Shareholders-Referencer.pdf)", the security trading on the London Stock Exchange is a Global Depository Receipt (GDR)<sup>†</sup>.

Looking at the [GDR's page](https://www.londonstockexchange.com/stock/RIGD/reliance-industries-limited/company-page?lang=en) on the London Stock Exchange website, I see:

> RIGD GDR (EACH REPR 2 ORD INR10 LEVEL1)(144A)

Similarly on the [Frankfurt Stock Exchange's website](https://www.boerse-frankfurt.de/equity/reliance-inds-gdr-144a-2):

> RELIANCE INDS GDR 144A/2

It appears that each GDR share represents 2 ordinary shares.

The underlying stock price on the NSE is about 2026 INR according to Google ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsCUz.png)), while the GDR is trading at about 55 USD on the London Stock Exchange.

2 * 2026 INR ≈ 55 USD

There is effectively no price discrepancy.

> What is the explanation for this?

The lesson is: you have to look at the depository receipt's ratio to the underlying. In this case, the ratio is 1 GDR to 2 ordinary shares.

---

<sup>†</sup> Oddly, the "Shareholders' Referencer" document says that the London Stock Exchange symbol for the GDR is "RILGD". In reality, the symbol is "RIGD".